# Generalize a (particular) script with a long awk operation involving 100+ columns

Tags: bash, awk, paste

Please only glance at the abundance of manual input in the code below, no need to understand it:

```
#!/bin/bash

paste A1.dat A2.dat A3.dat A4.dat A5.dat A6.dat > A.dat

awk '{print ($2 + $21 + $40 + $59 + $78 + $97), ($3 + $22 + $41 + $60 + $79 + $98), ($4 + $23 + $42 + $61 + $80 + $99) + ($6 + $25 + $44 + $63 + $82 + $101) + ($8 + $27 + $46 + $65 + $84 + $103), ($5 + $24 + $43 + $62 + $81 + $100) + ($7 + $26 + $45 + $64 + $83 + $102) + ($9 + $ 28 + $47 + $66 + $85 + $104), ($10 + $29 + $48 + $67 + $86 + $105) + ($12 + $31 + $50 + $69 + $88 + $107) + ($14 + $33 + $52 + $71 + $90 + $109) + ($16 + $35 + $54 + $73 + $92 + $111) + ($18 + $37 + $56 + $75 + $94 + $113), ($11 + $30 + $49 + $68 + $87 + $106) + ($13 + $32 + $51 + $70 + $89 + $108) + ($15 + $34 + $53 + $72 + $91 + $110) + ($17 + $36 + $55 + $74 + $93 + $112) + ($19 + $38 + $57 + $76 + $95 + $114)}' A.dat >> A_full.dat
```

**Code objective**: Take data stored in `n` input files each containing 19 columns of data and equal # of rows. Manipulate this data in a certain fashion to generate an output file with 7 columns of data and the same # of rows as each of the input files.

*What I did in the code above*: Used `paste` to merge all of the n input files (A?.dat) into 1 file (A.dat). Next, I use `awk` to manipulate the data in A.dat to get the output file (A_full.dat). This becomes unruly and cumbersome for a large value of n.

*My request*: Help me generalize the code for **any value of `n`**. The code I've posted above is for when n=6. To understand what data manipulation the code does, please look at the code below for n=2 (see explanation after the sample files):

```
#!/bin/bash

paste A1.dat A2.dat > A.dat

awk '{print $1, ($2 + $21), ($3 + $22), ($4 + $23) + ($6 + $25) + ($8 + $27), ($5 + $24) + ($7 + $26) + ($9 + $28), ($10 + $29) + ($12 + $31) + ($14 + $33) + ($16 + $35 ) + ($18 + $37), ($11 + $30) + ($13 + $32) + ($15 + $34) + ($17 + $36) + ($19 + $38)}' A.dat >> A_full.dat
```

*Sample files*:

A1.dat:

```
-0.908  0.3718E-03  0.2227E-02  0.1216E-05  0.6719E-05  0.1697E-05  0.1052E-04  0.1697E-05  0.1052E-04  0.5774E-07  0.3360E-06  0.5774E-07  0.3360E-06  0.5418E-06  0.3169E-05  0.1972E-06  0.1099E-05  0.1610E-05  0.9417E-05
-0.902  0.1042E-02  0.3365E-02  0.3427E-05  0.1021E-04  0.4837E-05  0.1619E-04  0.4837E-05  0.1619E-04  0.1623E-06  0.5093E-06  0.1623E-06  0.5093E-06  0.1522E-05  0.4803E-05  0.5530E-06  0.1661E-05  0.4522E-05  0.1427E-04
-0.895  0.1962E-02  0.4677E-02  0.6479E-05  0.1428E-04  0.9232E-05  0.2289E-04  0.9232E-05  0.2289E-04  0.3064E-06  0.7100E-06  0.3064E-06  0.7100E-06  0.2870E-05  0.6694E-05  0.1042E-05  0.2310E-05  0.8530E-05  0.1988E-04
-0.889  0.3067E-02  0.6167E-02  0.1019E-04  0.1893E-04  0.1470E-04  0.3064E-04  0.1470E-04  0.3064E-04  0.4806E-06  0.9388E-06  0.4806E-06  0.9388E-06  0.4500E-05  0.8850E-05  0.1629E-05  0.3047E-05  0.1337E-04  0.2629E-04
```

A2.dat:

```
-0.908  0.9081E-04  0.5463E-03  0.9126E-05  0.5564E-04  0.4880E-06  0.3004E-05  0.4880E-06  0.3004E-05  0.2218E-06  0.1311E-05  0.2218E-06  0.1311E-05  0.1433E-06  0.8079E-06  0.1452E-06  0.8808E-06  0.4262E-06  0.2402E-05
-0.902  0.2531E-03  0.8191E-03  0.2580E-04  0.8502E-04  0.1377E-05  0.4565E-05  0.1377E-05  0.4565E-05  0.6264E-06  0.2000E-05  0.6264E-06  0.2000E-05  0.3994E-06  0.1211E-05  0.4063E-06  0.1327E-05  0.1188E-05  0.3599E-05
-0.895  0.4742E-03  0.1130E-02  0.4894E-04  0.1194E-03  0.2604E-05  0.6378E-05  0.2604E-05  0.6378E-05  0.1187E-05  0.2805E-05  0.1187E-05  0.2805E-05  0.7483E-06  0.1670E-05  0.7638E-06  0.1839E-05  0.2225E-05  0.4963E-05
-0.889  0.7357E-03  0.1480E-02  0.7735E-04  0.1591E-03  0.4094E-05  0.8448E-05  0.4094E-05  0.8448E-05  0.1874E-05  0.3729E-05  0.1874E-05  0.3729E-05  0.1161E-05  0.2186E-05  0.1191E-05  0.2419E-05  0.3452E-05  0.6496E-05
```

A.dat:

```
-0.908  0.3718E-03  0.2227E-02  0.1216E-05  0.6719E-05  0.1697E-05  0.1052E-04  0.1697E-05  0.1052E-04  0.5774E-07  0.3360E-06  0.5774E-07  0.3360E-06  0.5418E-06  0.3169E-05  0.1972E-06  0.1099E-05  0.1610E-05  0.9417E-05       -0.908  0.9081E-04  0.5463E-03  0.9126E-05  0.5564E-04  0.4880E-06  0.3004E-05  0.4880E-06  0.3004E-05  0.2218E-06  0.1311E-05  0.2218E-06  0.1311E-05  0.1433E-06  0.8079E-06  0.1452E-06  0.8808E-06  0.4262E-06  0.2402E-05
-0.902  0.1042E-02  0.3365E-02  0.3427E-05  0.1021E-04  0.4837E-05  0.1619E-04  0.4837E-05  0.1619E-04  0.1623E-06  0.5093E-06  0.1623E-06  0.5093E-06  0.1522E-05  0.4803E-05  0.5530E-06  0.1661E-05  0.4522E-05  0.1427E-04       -0.902  0.2531E-03  0.8191E-03  0.2580E-04  0.8502E-04  0.1377E-05  0.4565E-05  0.1377E-05  0.4565E-05  0.6264E-06  0.2000E-05  0.6264E-06  0.2000E-05  0.3994E-06  0.1211E-05  0.4063E-06  0.1327E-05  0.1188E-05  0.3599E-05
-0.895  0.1962E-02  0.4677E-02  0.6479E-05  0.1428E-04  0.9232E-05  0.2289E-04  0.9232E-05  0.2289E-04  0.3064E-06  0.7100E-06  0.3064E-06  0.7100E-06  0.2870E-05  0.6694E-05  0.1042E-05  0.2310E-05  0.8530E-05  0.1988E-04       -0.895  0.4742E-03  0.1130E-02  0.4894E-04  0.1194E-03  0.2604E-05  0.6378E-05  0.2604E-05  0.6378E-05  0.1187E-05  0.2805E-05  0.1187E-05  0.2805E-05  0.7483E-06  0.1670E-05  0.7638E-06  0.1839E-05  0.2225E-05  0.4963E-05
-0.889  0.3067E-02  0.6167E-02  0.1019E-04  0.1893E-04  0.1470E-04  0.3064E-04  0.1470E-04  0.3064E-04  0.4806E-06  0.9388E-06  0.4806E-06  0.9388E-06  0.4500E-05  0.8850E-05  0.1629E-05  0.3047E-05  0.1337E-04  0.2629E-04       -0.889  0.7357E-03  0.1480E-02  0.7735E-04  0.1591E-03  0.4094E-05  0.8448E-05  0.4094E-05  0.8448E-05  0.1874E-05  0.3729E-05  0.1874E-05  0.3729E-05  0.1161E-05  0.2186E-05  0.1191E-05  0.2419E-05  0.3452E-05  0.6496E-05
```

A_full.dat:

```
-0.908 0.00046261 0.0027733 1.4712e-05 8.9407e-05 3.62278e-06 2.10697e-05
-0.902 0.0012951 0.0041841 4.1655e-05 0.00013674 1.01681e-05 3.18896e-05
-0.895 0.0024362 0.005807 7.9091e-05 0.000192216 1.91659e-05 4.4386e-05
-0.889 0.0038027 0.007647 0.000125128 0.000256206 3.00122e-05 5.86236e-05
```

**More on the 7 columns of the output file (A_full.dat)**:

- All of the input A?.dat files have the same values in the col 1. A_full.dat must also have the same col 1.
- col 2 of A_full.dat should be the summation of col 2 of all A?.dat files.
- col 3 of A_full.dat should be the summation of col 3 of all A?.dat files.
- col 4 of A_full.dat should be the summation of cols 4, 6, and 8 of all A?.dat files.
- col 5 of A_full.dat should be the summation of cols 5, 7, and 9 of all A?.dat files.
- col 6 of A_full.dat should be the summation of cols 10, 12, 14, 16, and 18 of all A?.dat files.
- col 7 of A_full.dat should be the summation of cols 11, 13, 15, 17, and 19 of all A?.dat files.

At first, I posted this question in a confusing manner, but with the help of @markp-fuso's input, I've edited it to make it easier to comprehend.

Comment: If you could explain the logic behind your maths(how are you adding or subtracting) then we could suggest something to with pragmatically here, kindly do add more information on logic part in your question and let us know then.

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. Obviously don't use 100 fields, use 10 or so instead. You're asking for help with a script to parse `A.dat` so we don't need to see the `paste` command that creates `A.dat` just minimal versions of `A.dat` and `A_full.dat` and your attempted awk script to work on THAT input.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sure.

Comment: how many rows in a particular file?  do all files have the same number of columns and rows? does the output need to be ordered (eg, ordered by $1)?

Comment: assuming the same number of columns and rows in each source file, a general solution would be to have `awk` process the individual datafiles (`A?.dat`), storing intermediate values in a set of arrays; `awk` would thus be simulating the `paste` operation (so need for the `paste` call); and since `awk` can process a largish number of input files the same `awk` solution could be used for n=2, n=6, ... n=50, etc.

Comment: [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63903273/optimize-a-particular-script-with-a-long-awk-operation-involving-100-columns#comment113001402_63903273) please add a [mcve]. See [ask] and look at other questions on this forum if that's not clear. Also clarify in what way you want to `optimize ` the script - less code, less memory used, less overall execution time, all of that and/or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton sorry, I'm trying to improve the question. Give me a little time.

Comment: @markp-fuso All of the `An.dat` files have the same # of rows and columns. The output needs to be ordered by $1.

Comment: I would suggest further editing: 1) provide sample input files `A1.dat` and `A2.dat`, 2) provide the desired output corresponding to the data in these 2x files and 3) consider reforming the explanation based on how to get from these 'raw' files to the desired output; consider reviewing my answer for what I think you're attempting to do ... and assuming I'm (fairly) correct then update your question from a clarity perspective ?

Comment: @EdMorton for this particular case the inclusion of the `paste` command is quite useful in that it lets us know that we're dealing with `n` input files; so instead of trying to deal with a single input file of `n x 19` columns we can consider solutions that deal with `n` number of files each with 19 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: Updated based on OPs latest changes (include field $1 in the output), and incorporating EdMorton's suggestion for the `awk/for` loop.

---

Based on OP's current `awk` command ...

```
awk '{print ($2 + $21 + $40 + $59 + $78 + $97), ($3 + $22 + $41 + $60 + $79 + $98), ($4 + $23 + $42 + $61 + $80 + $99) + ($6 + $25 + $44 + $63 + $82 + $101) + ($8 + $27 + $46 + $65 + $84 + $103), ($5 + $24 + $43 + $62 + $81 + $100) + ($7 + $26 + $45 + $64 + $83 + $102) + ($9 + $ 28 + $47 + $66 + $85 + $104), ($10 + $29 + $48 + $67 + $86 + $105) + ($12 + $31 + $50 + $69 + $88 + $107) + ($14 + $33 + $52 + $71 + $90 + $109) + ($16 + $35 + $54 + $73 + $92 + $111) + ($18 + $37 + $56 + $75 + $94 + $113), ($11 + $30 + $49 + $68 + $87 + $106) + ($13 + $32 + $51 + $70 + $89 + $108) + ($15 + $34 + $53 + $72 + $91 + $110) + ($17 + $36 + $55 + $74 + $93 + $112) + ($19 + $38 + $57 + $76 + $95 + $114)}' A.dat >> A_full.dat
```

... as well as an assortment of comments and edits, I come away with the following:

- all input files have 19 fields
- all input files have the same number of rows
- unsure what, if anything, is to be done with field #1 (due to question edits and confusing explanation)
- desired output consists of 7x columns (`col1` to `col7`) for each set of input rows
- `col1` : copy of field #1 from first file (field #1 should be the same in all input files)
- `col2` : summation of field #2 from all input files
- `col3` : (negated) summation of field #3 from all input files
- `col4` : summation of fields #4, #6 and #8 from all input files
- `col5` : (negated) summation of fields #5, #7 and #9 from all input files
- `col6` : summation of fields #10, #12, #14, #16 and #18 from all input files
- `col7` : summation of fields #11, #13, #15, #17 and #19 from all input files
- for now I'm assuming we want the output rows ordered by the same order in which they're read from the input files (ie, input NR == output NR)
- OP needs a solution that can work with `n` number of input files

Instead of `paste`(ing) the `n` input files into a single big file (`A.dat`) and then having `awk` parse the `n x 19` columns, I propose having `awk` read the individual data files (`A?.dat`) and accumulate the desired data values 'on the fly'.

One `awk` solution:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { col1[FNR]=$1 }
        { col2[FNR]+=($2)
          col3[FNR]-=($3)
          col4[FNR]+=($4 + $6 + $8)
          col5[FNR]-=($5 + $7 + $9)
          col6[FNR]+=($10 + $12 + $14 + $16 + $18)
          col7[FNR]+=($11 + $13 + $15 + $17 + $19)
        }
END     { for ( i=1 ; i <= FNR ; i++ )
              printf "%s %7.5f %7.5f %8.6f %8.6f %d %d\n", col1[i], col2[i], col3[i], col4[i], col5[i], col6[i], col7[i]
    }
' A1.dat A2.dat A3.dat ... An.dat
```

**NOTE**: `printf` formats are based on the limited sample output provided by OP; may need to adjust these based on the desired results from a larger data set.

**NOTE**: One downside to this `awk` solution is that we have to store all (output) data in a set of arrays which, in turn, could lead to memory usage issues if we're dealing with a large volume of rows.

Parsing the OPs sample input file (`A.dat`) back out into the first 2x original data files:

```
$ cat A1.dat
  4.429  0.3620E-01  0.3919E-01  0.1063E-01  0.9525E-02  0.9146E-02  0.7986E-02  0.9146E-02  0.7986E-02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
  4.436  0.3489E-01  0.3876E-01  0.1022E-01  0.9461E-02  0.8803E-02  0.7872E-02  0.8803E-02  0.7872E-02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
  4.442  0.3364E-01  0.3852E-01  0.9760E-02  0.9469E-02  0.8402E-02  0.7801E-02  0.8402E-02  0.7801E-02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
  4.449  0.3260E-01  0.3917E-01  0.9364E-02  0.9753E-02  0.8040E-02  0.8083E-02  0.8040E-02  0.8083E-02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00

$ cat A2.dat
   4.429  0.4333E-01  0.3393E-01  0.6788E-02  0.6654E-02  0.8228E-02  0.7242E-02  0.8228E-02  0.7242E-02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
   4.436  0.4101E-01  0.3372E-01  0.6687E-02  0.6563E-02  0.7849E-02  0.7179E-02  0.7849E-02  0.7179E-02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
   4.442  0.3861E-01  0.3437E-01  0.6561E-02  0.6437E-02  0.7440E-02  0.7192E-02  0.7440E-02  0.7192E-02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
   4.449  0.3646E-01  0.3667E-01  0.6462E-02  0.6514E-02  0.7091E-02  0.7443E-02  0.7091E-02  0.7443E-02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
```

Running the proposed `awk` solution against these 2x input files generates:

```
$ awk '{ col1[FNR]+= .... }' A1.dat A2.dat
4.429 0.07953 -0.07312 0.052166 -0.046635 0 0
4.436 0.07590 -0.07248 0.050211 -0.046126 0 0
4.442 0.07225 -0.07289 0.048005 -0.045892 0 0
4.449 0.06906 -0.07584 0.046088 -0.047319 0 0
```

Comment: I now realise the question was posed confusingly, but you got it all correct. Your solution works perfectly well, doesn't even take a second given that each of the A?.dat files, at a time, has less than 10000 lines. Thank you for your help. I'll edit the question to make it easier to comprehend.

Comment: yes, 10K lines, times 6 numeric values (stored in the array), is rather small (in terms of memory usage) and time to process; if you find yourself having to process 10's/100's of millions of lines (per file) then you'll likely run into some memory issues, though total processing time should be (somewhat) linear for the large volume of rows

Comment: `for (i in col1)` will shuffle the output into hash or some other order, you should use `for (i=1; i <= FNR; i++)` or `for (i=1; i in col1; i++)` if that's a concern. If you get the same output order as the input order for the current or any other input, that's just a coincidence for this particular awk version on this particular computer with  this particular input and can't be relied upon for anything else.

Comment: @EdMorton yea, I remember I faced such hash table storage issue with for a in something construct. Thank you for the warning.

Comment: To make the question less verbose I removed the part about $1 or the first column of every A?.dat file. $1 for all of the A?.dat files is the same (it's a list of values for a materials's properties). The objective is for $1 of the output file to be equal to $1 of these files as well. Is there a way to incorporate that in this `awk` construct?

Comment: @HitanshuSachania please update the question with sample input and desired output; I think I know what you're looking for but seeing a sample of the desired output (in the question) would help

Comment: @HitanshuSachania - answer updated to include dumping field #1 to the output

Comment: Thanks a ton, @markp-fuso. How could I not think of just storing $1 into another col array.