# Will `for var in something` assign `var` to values in `something` in the order of its indices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

In a comment to an answer to another question, at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63906192/9671786, I came to know for loop in awk doesn't follow the order of indices. For instance, `for i in A` where `A` is an array of some length `n`, `i` won't necessarily be assigned values `A[0], A[1], A[2], ..., A[n-1]`, in that order. Is this true for python as well?

Comment: What research did you do? What have you read that you came to the conclusion that it is not true? `A[0], A[1], A[2],` in `awk` all arrays are associative, not indexed.

Comment: That is, an array in `awk` is really more like a `dict` in Python.

Comment: Alright, didn't know that about `awk`. To what are entries in an `awk` array associated with?

Comment: @KamilCuk I thought "What research did the OP do?" too. Then I started to read the Python documentation to show how easy this information can be found ... and up to now I still haven't found it.

Comment: Found it in the tutorial in the chapter [The `for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) : "Python’s `for` statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a list or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence."

Comment: @Matthias thank you for the reference.

Comment: @Matthias Link is wrong, [it's here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). And "the order that they appear in the sequence" is still vague. Who says that that order corresponds to the indexes?

Comment: @superbrain Thanks for the corrected link. Looks like it was a copy&paste error on my side.

Comment: Concerning the order of the sequence one can deduce that from the description of `list.append`: "Add an item to the end of the list.". But I think we agree, that somehow the documentation sounds like "Well, we all know how it is working" and this information should be somewhere else in the documentation.

Comment: @Matthias Yeah, "we all know" might be the explanation :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the defining features of a *list* (not array) in Python is that it represents an *ordered* sequence of elements. When you iterate over the list, you are guaranteed to see the elements in the order of the integer keys used to index the list.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.